# Function call in for loop condition?

Tags: c++, c++11

If I have function call in for loop condition like this:

```
for (auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end(), ++it) {}
```

is it called on each iteration? I expect that yes. Is compiler allow to optimized it away? Are current compilers smart enough to do so? Or am I better using something like following:

```
for (auto it = s.begin(), auto end = s.end(); it != end; ++it) {}
```

?

Comment: As you are using C++11, consider using the range-based for loop which avoids this issue.

Comment: @NeilKirk not usable in my case, I actually need the iterator to do fun stuff with.

Comment: Personally I write my loops using your second approach, then I don't have to worry about it. I don't know how far it matters or not in practice.

Comment: I always use your second version of the for loop. btw the second `auto` is redundant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the program has to call the second expression `it != s.end()` at each iteration. I think the compiler can optimize this away in certain situation.

Anyway, don't do the compiler's job. If it can be optimized, there's a great chance the compiler already does it, and anyway this call has no significant performance hit.

If your case permit it, you should use a range based for loop:

```
for (auto& i : s) {
    // instructions
}
```

That way, the compiler have even more opportunities to optimize your code and it is easier to read.

If you want some example about how much the compiler can optimize stuff, look at this! http://ridiculousfish.com/blog/posts/will-it-optimize.html

Comment: I would normally use that, but I actually have need to manipulate the iterator a bit, so the classic foreach loop won't work for me

Comment: Ah, use the classic for loop then. But again, the compiler is very smart. There's no need to complicate the code in this case.

Comment: I edited my answer to be more generic and I just added a link to a great article.

Answer (score 6):

In

```
for ( auto it = s.begin(); it != s.end(), ++it )
```

`s.begin()` is called only once.
`s.end()` and `operator++()` (for `++it`) are called in each iteration of the loop.

> Is compiler allow to optimized it away?

The compiler can optimize away the call to `s.end()` depending on the compiler, the implementation, and the optimization level. I will be surprised if it can optimize away the `operator++()` call.

> Are current compilers smart enough to do so?

Can't answer that.

> Or am I better using something like following:

```
for (auto it = s.begin(), auto end = s.end(); it != end; ++it) {}
```

It won't hurt. However, it can be a problem if `s` is modified in the loop. If `s` is not modified in the loop, I would recommend using this approach.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is formally called at each iteration. And yes, current compilers will likely inline the function and see that `s.end()` returns the same value (pointer?) each time.

There is no need for you to complicate the code, unless profiling shows that this is a bottleneck in your program (extremely unlikely).